# stopping a recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, recursion, permutation

there are 10 numbers that have to satisfy the following equations:

(a[0]+a[1]+a[3]+a[4]) =S

(a[9]+a[0]+a[7]+a[8]) =S

(a[2]+a[1]+a[9]+a[8]) =S

(a[2]+a[3]+a[5]+a[6]) =S

(a[8]+a[7]+a[5]+a[4]) =S

i have the 10 numbers in an array, and by using a recursive permutation algorithm, i try to find all the possible permutations to check if the numbers satisfy the above equations.
as soon as the correct permutation is found, i want the program to return true and stop generating the other permutations. here is the code, but it returns false always.
for e.g for numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12 and S=24, we have an asnwer: 1,8,2,12,3,6,4,10,5,9 
but the algorithm returns false anyway!!!

```
bool permute(int *array,int i,int length, int S) { 


  if (length == i){

    if( check( array, S) )
            return true;
        else
        return false;   

  }
  int j = i;
  for (j = i; j < length; j++) { 
     swap(array+i,array+j);
     if( check( array, S) )
            return true;
     permute(array,i+1,length, S);


     swap(array+i,array+j);
     if( check( array, S) )
            return true;
  }

  return false;
}

bool check( int* a, int S){
    if((a[0]+a[1]+a[3]+a[4]) ==S && (a[9]+a[0]+a[7]+a[8]) ==S && (a[2]+a[1]+a[9]+a[8]) ==S && (a[2]+a[3]+a[5]+a[6]) ==S && (a[8]+a[7]+a[5]+a[4]) ==S)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to address the return status.
`permute(array,i+1,length, S);` returns a status - check whether it's true and return in this case:
`if(permute(array,i+1,length, S)) return true;`.